# Gfci breaker will not turn on at hot tub disconnect

Tags: electrical, hot-tub

I installed a new GFCI breaker for a hot tub on the deck in a separate box from the main panel. Wired it to the hot tub . but it will not turn on.

Would a wire at a lug not fully secured cause the breaker to stay tripped?

Comment: There is power going to the box with the breaker in it, right?  That power isn't still disconnected?

Comment: Did you install the breaker correctly (following installation instructions)?

Comment: A photo of the GFCI connections in the new box would probably show what is wrong.

Comment: We do need more information, history, etc.

Comment: Can you post photos of how the GFCI breaker is wired?